# Computing sums of divisors in $O(\sqrt n)$ time?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recursive-algorithms

I have a sequence: $1,3,5,8,10,14,16,20,23,27,\dots$

I know that the recursive relation is:

$$p[i] := p[i-1] + \text{number of factors of $i$}, \quad \text{with $p[1]=1$.}$$

How do I solve this recursive relation in $O(n^{0.5})$ time? I have to write a program for it, and $n$ can be as large as $10^9$. So, some appropriate precomputation and prestorage is allowed, provided that they comply (memory and time wise) with the range of $n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for $p_n = \sum_{k=1}^n d(k)$, where $d(k)$ is the number of divisors of $k$.

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3369) claims an algorithm running in $O(n^{1/3})$ time and $O(\log n)$ space. See also [Deterministic methods to find primes](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-278/S0025-5718-2011-02542-1/home.html) by Tao, Croot Ill and Helfgott sprung from a [Polymath](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Polymath1) project.

Note that formula (4) in the first link gives a simple $O(\sqrt n)$ algorithm:

$$p(n) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n} \rfloor} \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor- \lfloor\sqrt n \rfloor^2$$

Comment: Ummm...How did they arrive at this function. I did understand the way the mapping was done, but how did they arrive at this?

Comment: @sudeepdino008 At least we can verify that (if $n$ is not a square) $p(n)-p(n-1)=2\sum (\lfloor\frac nk\rfloor - \lfloor \frac {n-1}k\rfloor) = 2\sum_{d|n, d^2<n}1$ as required. And if $n=m^2$ is a square, the additional summand $2m$ is correctly compensated by $m^2-(m-1)^2=2m-1$.