# Find number of divisors upto $10^9$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am new to number theory, I have to find the number of divisors up to $10^9$, but i dont know how to do it efficiently and store it in an array in 'c'.
I am using sieve algo to find the number of divisors, here is what I am doing

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 100000
int div[N+1];
void divisors() {
  int i,len,j;
  for(i=2;i<=N;i++) {
     for(j=i;j<N;j+=i)
      div[j]++;
  }
}

int main(){
  int i;
  divisors();
  for(i=1;i<N;i++) printf("%d\n",div[i]+1);
  return 0;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Every number up to $n$ is a divisor of something.

Comment: Do you mean, given any number up to 10^9, you must list down all its divisors?

Comment: @markovchain I have just to tell number of divisors

Comment: For each $1<i<j<10^9$, you could check if $j\%i\equiv 0$. If so, add $i$ to the array of divisors of $j$ (however you'd like to do that).

Comment: Do you need all divisor counts, or just the divisor count of some numbers $\leqslant 10^9$? If only some, about how many?

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually I need to find the sum of divisors of all numbers upto 10^9, so I am calculating divisors of all numbers upto 10^9 then I will be taking sum of numbers.

Comment: Aha. Sum of number of divisors. Hang on a minute, I'm going to post a link to a dupe.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486504/how-to-simplify-this-summation-containing-floor) it is. Comes up a lot recently.

Comment: @DanielFischer I found there ∑n≤Nd(n)=NlogN+(2γ−1)N+O(sqrt(N)),  what that O(sqrt(N)) means, how to calculate that..?

Comment: @avinashse $O(\sqrt{N})$ means something bounded by a constant multiple of $\sqrt{N}$. But since you want an exact answer, look at the formula in my answer, that gives a relatively efficient way of computing the number (you can still improve on that, but for the online judges/programming competitions, it ought to be efficient enough when directly translated into code).

Comment: @DanielFischer you mentioned there upto 1000 its efficient,but i ve to compute for upto 10^9.

Comment: @DanielFischer And I will be really very thankful if you kindly help me suggesting any easy starting book for number theory along with video tutorials :)

Comment: It's efficient for some several thousand _queries_. If you have many more queries to serve, it becomes more efficient to compute all the sums and look them up - well, you will have memory problems with $10^9$ stored `unsigned long long`, so you'd have to trade some speed for space.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486864 Considering the amount of questions this has generated lately, I wonder where it comes from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simplify this summation containing floor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486504/how-to-simplify-this-summation-containing-floor)

Answer (score 1):

We are interested in the number of divisors, so first you have to do a prime factorization for every number. We'll take $36091440$ as an example. We can write it as:

$$36091440 = 2^4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11 \cdot 31$$

Now we'll generate all combinations to get all divisors. First for $2$ there are 5 option, we can include $0,1,2,3 \text{ or } 4$ $2$'s in the product that we'll give a divisor. So the number of option is the value of the exponent of the prime factor plus 1.

So this number will have:

$$5 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 480$$

So there will be $480$ divisors.

Note that we calculate the option when none of the prime factors is included into the product, because also $1$ is a divisor of any number.